# Add variable into dictionary using loop condition

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have created a dictionary like below;

1. I want to use loop add `'Honors': 'No'` if GPA is less than 3.5, otherwise `'Honors': 'Yes'` into existing dictionary.

   Student = {'A1': {'Student_Name': 'Jason','Class_Year': 1,'CGPA': 3.15},'A2': {'Student_Name': 'Henry','Class_Year': 2,'CGPA': 3.65}}

So the expected result will be like below;

```
Student = {'A1': {'Student_Name': 'Jason','Class_Year': 1,'CGPA': 3.15,'Honors': 'No'},'A2': {'Student_Name': 'Henry','Class_Year': 2,'CGPA': 3.65,'Honors': 'Yes'}}
```

2. How i can use loop to calculate average GPA for my dictionary?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please give a minimum reproducable example of the code you tried and what your problems are. SO does not support questions like "Write me a program" Sorry!

Comment: What have you tried, and what **specific** problem did you encounter?

Comment: do you have to use a dictionary? have you tried csv?

Answer (score 1):

**PART1:**

So for your example:

```
Student = {'A1': {'Student_Name': 'Jason','Class_Year': 1,'CGPA': 3.15},'A2': {'Student_Name': 'Henry','Class_Year': 2,'CGPA': 3.65}}
```

It boils down to just understand how to run through a dictionary:

```
for st, stuff in Student.items():
    if float(stuff['CGPA'])<3.5:
        Student[st]['Honors']='No'
    
    else:
        Student[st]['Honors']='Yes'
```

The final result would be:

```
{'A1': {'Student_Name': 'Jason', 'Class_Year': 1, 'CGPA': 3.15, 'Honors': 'No'}, 'A2': {'Student_Name': 'Henry', 'Class_Year': 2, 'CGPA': 3.65, 'Honors': 'Yes'}}
```

**PART2:**
Just small addition and that's all you need:

```
gpa_sum = 0
for st, stuff in Student.items():
    gpa_sum+=float(stuff['CGPA'])
    if float(stuff['CGPA'])<3.5:
        Student[st]['Honors']='No'
    
    else:
        Student[st]['Honors']='Yes'
        
print(f'The average GPA is :{gpa_sum/len(Student)}')
```

Output:

```
The average GPA is :3.4
```

Comment: You can just use `for st in Student:`, otherwise yes.

Comment: Well yeah, Python has so many ways to solve same thing :D

Answer (score 0):

```
In [26]: Student
Out[26]:
{'A1': {'Student_Name': 'Jason', 'Class_Year': 1, 'CGPA': 3.15},
 'A2': {'Student_Name': 'Henry', 'Class_Year': 2, 'CGPA': 3.65}}

In [27]: for s in Student:
    ...:     if Student[s]['CGPA'] >= 3.5:
    ...:         Student[s]['Honors'] = 'Yes'
    ...:     else:
    ...:         Student[s]['Honors'] = 'No'
    ...:

In [28]: Student
Out[28]:
{'A1': {'Student_Name': 'Jason',
  'Class_Year': 1,
  'CGPA': 3.15,
  'Honors': 'No'},
 'A2': {'Student_Name': 'Henry',
  'Class_Year': 2,
  'CGPA': 3.65,
  'Honors': 'Yes'}}
```

**Average GPA**

```
In [29]: sum([Student[s]['CGPA'] for s in Student]) / len([Student[s]['CGPA'] for s in Student])
Out[29]: 3.4
```

Comment: thanks a lot, any idea use loop to calculate the average GPA?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the outer dictionary and then evaluate the inner dictionary Grade:

```
students = {
    'A1': {'Student_Name': 'Jason','Class_Year': 1,'CGPA': 3.15},
    'A2': {'Student_Name': 'Henry','Class_Year': 2,'CGPA': 3.65}
}

for student, info in students.items():
    if info["CGPA"] < 3.5:
        info["Honors"] = "No"
    else:
        info["Honors"] = "Yes"
```

By convention try to avoid Capital string in your variable.